# ploting histogram of node degrees (networkx)

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a network that I created with networkx.

I want to see the distribution of all of the nodes in the network compering to specific nodes in the same network.

I created two dicts of the nodes degrees as follow:

```
df = df.T.corr(method="spearman")


edges = df.stack().reset_index()
edges.columns = ['var_1','var_2','correlation']
edges = edges.loc[ (edges['correlation'] < -0.6) | (edges['correlation'] > 0.6) & (edges['var_1'] != edges['var_2']) ].copy()

#create undirected graph with weights corresponding to the correlation magnitude
G0 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'var_1', 'var_2', edge_attr=['correlation'])


print(nx.info(G0))

# =============================================================================
degrees = [val for (node, val) in G0.degree()]
degrees2 = [val for (node, val) in G0.degree(['Aureobasidium', 'Cladosporium', 'Alternaria',
                                              'Filobasidium', 'Vishniacozyma',
                                              'Sporobolomyces', 'Sphingomonas',
                                              'Methylobacterium'])]
```

how can I represent the nodes degree on a simple barplot (with two bars next to each other)
when the Y axis is the count of each degree, and the X axis is the degree

I found this code: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_degree_histogram.html
that is what I want without the small network.

Igot this
[image]

while I want the bars will be next to each other

any halp will be grate! Tnx!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the exact code you used for the bar plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo plot for a random graph.

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100, .5)
degrees = [val for (node, val) in G.degree()]
degrees2 = [abs(d - 1) for d in degrees]

d1 = np.array(degrees)
d2 = np.array(degrees2)

plt.hist([d1, d2], label=['d1', 'd2'])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]